# Custom Slider In WordPress

Tags: frontend, slider, wordpress-theming, customization, web-frontend

I need to create a custom slider in my WordPress website just like **Tata Group** website have **https://www.tata.com/**
I have tried using WordPress plugin but didn't work my way. I need assistance to figure out how Can I create the exact same slider for my WordPress website

Answer (score 0):

For making something like this you should know JQuery.
If you don't, you can use these two plugins They help you make your slider

https://www.sliderrevolution.com

https://layerslider.com

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your answer. Actually I'm looking to create it with custom code

Comment: @MalikZeeshan The example is custom code. In your question you are refering with plugin.